# Using binary search in B-Tree

Tags: algorithm

In the book CLRS(Introduction to algorithms), B-Tree is introduced in Chapter 18. And it has the following property(P488)

> the x.n keys themselves, x.key<sub>1</sub>, ..., x.key<sub>x.n</sub> stored in  nondecreasing order

But in the procedure for searching an element in B-Tree, inserting an element into B-Tree, CLRS uses linear search instead of binary search in searching for the key in a particular node.

Why does it do that? Would it get better performence with binary search?

Comment: I don't know the source, but I'd guess that you search "linearly" from the root to the leafs of the tree, branching left or right depending on the node's values. In effect, this is, of course, a binary search, given the structure of the tree.

Comment: I edited the post. "Linearly" refers to searching in a particular node. You may refer to CLRS pseudocode for better understanding.

Comment: Well, I can't refer to the pseudocode if I don't have the source. But I understand that you do not mean searching the node, but searching the key _within_ the node. As I understand it, each node has a fixed (small) number of values, so using binary search here might either be overkill, or an implementation detail left out by the authors.

Comment: They probably just wanted to keep things simple.  Practical implementations use binary search in the node if the fan-out is big enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow the order to vary, then you're right: doing a binary search still results in time complexity in `O(log n)`, while doing a linear search results in `O(t log n)`. But if you consider the order (maximum degree) of the B-tree fixed, then whether you do a binary or linear search doesn't matter to the time complexity. Since the order is generally determined by considerations like cache line size, that's a reasonable simplification to make.

In practice, a linear search will often give you better performance because it can be done with less branching and is more amenable to SIMD processing. Actual B-tree implementations will either use only linear search, or an initial binary search followed by a linear search. The wall-clock time spent searching will be dominated by the time waiting to fetch nodes, not by the search for the appropriate children.

Comment: how should we do this binary search in B-tree nodes in python? @Sneftel